# how can change filesystem from ext4 to xfs

Tags: linux, centos7, filesystems, cloud

how can I change filesystem from ext4 to xfs without data losing?
I've centos7 on Arvan cloud (IaaS like linode) and I don't have special permisson.

Comment: off-topic. changing the filesystem must always be a done via recreation of the filesystem. So backup, format and recovery is always the point. Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: @djdomi I disagree that changing the FS should be done via FS recreation. You realize this is longer and requires a lot of tinkering? So what are the benefits compared to using e.g. a `btrfs-convert` for a ext4 → btrfs case? I also did not understand the second part of your comment. Is there something unreasonable in the practice of converting one FS to another?

Comment: So, FTR, I think `fstransform` might be what you're looking for, its usage is simply a `sudo fstransform /dev/sdX xfs`. However, I'm not posting this as an answer as I could not make it work, for me it fails with `internal error! assertion failed: last_logical <= logical`. I didn't have time to look at it ATM, maybe I will at some later point as I have a ext4-based system at work that I need to support reflinks *(hence be on XFS or BTRFS)*.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a backup
2. unmount the disk/partition/volume
3. format the disk/partition/volume with mkfs.xfs
4. restore the data from backup.

Comment: that's what I was talking about ;l